# Is it possible to use try with resources along with an input stream?

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner, inputstream, try-with-resources

When implementing try with resources I am creating a Scanner object via `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)` within () of the try statement.
In the try block, I am prompting the user to enter a numeric value, reading it via `sc.nextLine()` and utilizing `parseDouble` to convert it to a method.
I utilize a do-while loop to re-prompt the user to enter a value if an invalid value was entered initially.

However, if the user enters an invalid value, the input stream closes, `NumberFormatException` is caught but during the second iteration of the do-while loop, a 'No line found' NoSuchElementException is thrown and infinitely thereafter due to the 'stream closed' java.io.IOException.
Is there a way to circumvent this while utilizing try with resources?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  int x = 1;

  do {
      try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
          System.out.print("Enter a numeric value: ");
          String input1 = sc.nextLine();
          Double d1;
          d1 = Double.parseDouble(input1);
          System.out.print("Enter a numeric value: ");
          String input2 = sc.nextLine();
          Double d2;
          d2 = Double.parseDouble(input2); 
          System.out.print("Choose an operation (+ - * /): ");
          String input3 = sc.nextLine();
          //sc.close();

          switch (input3) {
              case "+":
                  Double result = d1 + d2;
                  System.out.println("The answer is " + result);
                  break;
              case "-":
                  Double result1 = d1 - d2;
                  System.out.println("The answer is " + result1);
                  break;
              case "*":
                  Double result2 = d1 * d2;
                  System.out.println("The answer is " + result2);
                  break; 
              case "/":
                  Double result3 = d1 / d2;
                  System.out.println("The answer is " + result3);
                  break;
              default:
                  System.out.println("Unrecognized Operation!");
                  break;
          }
          x++;        
      } 
      catch (NumberFormatException e){ 
          System.out.println("Number formatting exception "+e.getMessage());
          System.out.println("Enter a proper value");    
      }
      catch (Exception e1){
          System.out.println("Arbitrary error encountered"+e1.getMessage());
      }
  }
  while(x==1);

}
```

Comment: It's working, but you don't want to do this **in** your loop; because closing the `Scanner` ***also*** closes `System.in`. Move the `try` to outside the loop and you should be good to go.

Comment: Closing resources which you've opened is a good habit. However, `Scanner` wraps stdin, which you didn't open. The general rule of thumb is _"do not close what you haven't opened"_. The JVM opened stdin, so leave it to the JVM to close it.

Comment: Moving the try outside the loop would exclude the catch statements and break re prompting if an invalid value is entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already said by others in the comments, you shouldn’t use try-with-resource with a resource you didn’t open yourself, especially not with `System.in`, which should never be closed by an application.

Besides that, you should prefer testing conditions beforehand, instead of catching exceptions. Further, try to avoid code duplication and you’ll end up at a much simpler solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\R");
    System.out.print("Enter first numeric value: ");
    double d1 = getDouble(sc);
    System.out.print("Enter second numeric value: ");
    double d2 = getDouble(sc);
    System.out.print("Choose an operation (+ - * /): ");
    while(!sc.hasNext("[-+*/]")) {
      System.out.println(sc.next()+" is not a valid operation");
    }
    String operation = sc.next();

    double result;
    switch (operation) {
        case "+": result = d1 + d2; break;
        case "-": result = d1 - d2; break;
        case "*": result = d1 * d2; break; 
        case "/": result = d1 / d2; break;
        default:
            throw new AssertionError("should not happen due to pretest");
    }
    System.out.println(d1+operation+d2);
    System.out.println("The answer is " + result);
}    
private static double getDouble(Scanner sc) {
    while(!sc.hasNextDouble()) {
        System.out.println(sc.next()+" is not a number");
    }
    return sc.nextDouble();
}
```

This solution uses `hasNextDouble()` to ask the scanner whether the next token has a double format and only if that’s acknowledged, the application will fetch it via `nextDouble()`. Otherwise, it uses `next()` to fetch the invalid token, which serves both, reporting and removing it from the unprocessed input. Likewise, `hasNext("[-+*/]")` checks whether the input matches one the the supported four operators.

Since the compiler doesn’t understand that now only one of the four valid inputs may occur, we have to put a throwing statement to the `default` case of the `switch`, as otherwise the compiler will say that `result` may not have been initialized. We could initialize `result` to a default value instead, but it’s better to have a strong signal if the program flow doesn’t work as expected, instead of printing a default value as wrong result.

The `Scanner` uses configurable delimiters to decide what constitutes a token, so this solution uses `useDelimiter("\\R")` to use line breaks as delimiter, to consider each line a token, like your original code. So the [`Pattern` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for a full description of the syntax.

Comment: Interesting solution. One could also use break instead of throwing the assertion error in the default case of the switch statement, correct? I assume throwing the error is best practice even though it’s a redundant mechanism. Are there scenarios in which the pretest could be breached?

Comment: If you only use `break`, it would just leave the `switch` statement, trying to proceed. The compiler would reject that possible program flow, because it would access an uninitialized `result` variable. You could use `return` instead. But it doesn’t matter what you put at a case that should never happen, as long as it doesn’t happen. When the situation that ought to be impossible does happen, you want to know it, rather than having a silent return that doesn’t tell what happened. If it happens, we have a bug, either on our side or (unlikely but not impossible) in the compiler or `Scanner` class

Comment: Hmm. I assume continue would yield the same effect as break if the result variable is not initialized?

Comment: `continue` requires a loop and in my answer there is no loop around the `switch` statement. It would be possible to write a loop reading via `sc.next()` without pretest, doing the `switch` with `default: continue;`, followed by using the `result`. Since then, the `continue` would skip the use of `result`, it would work.